# Is there a general word/phrase for bias against a group?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I think prejudice is too general.
The definition Google gives me for prejudice is:
"preconceived opinion that is not based on reason or actual experience."
 - it doesn't specify that this preconceived opinion is due to membership in some group (or, more specifically, perceived membership in a group), although it seems to have that connotation, so maybe that is what I should go with.

I think bigotry is too strong.
For bigotry, we have (wikipedia): "Bigotry is a state of mind where a person strongly and unfairly dislikes other people, ideas, etc. "

Bigotry sort of connotes hatred, not just bias.

I want a way to describe the fact that a particular statement reveals an attitude that is unfairly biased against a culturally significant group, which may or may not be intentional or malicious.

Comment: What kind of group are we talking about? There are terms for discriminating against certain groups, such as sexist, racist, etc.

Comment: maybe **repugnance**, **dislike**, **antipathy**, **repulsion**?

Comment: bias? (filler words)

Comment: Are you sure 'prejudice' is too general?

Comment: Please give an example sentence to explain how you would like to use this word.

Comment: You want a general word, but not too general??

Comment: I think discriminatory might be a good option...

Answer (score 2):

*[Prejudice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prejudice)* is used to refer to any kind of prejudgement based on one or more traits or characteristics.  I think that is *exactly* what you are looking for.

However, it comes down to how you define "a group."  Since you can group people based on their traits or characteristics, then *prejudice* fits nicely.

On the other hand, if you mean "a group" as in "a voluntary association of individuals", then perhaps the more specific phrase *[social prejudice](http://www.motivation-tools.com/workplace/social_prejudice.htm)* is what you are looking for.

Maybe the recently coined *[friendism](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=friendism)* might be more appropriate.  *Friendism* is prejudice against those who are not your friends.

A perfect term might be *[group-ism](http://tonoticeandtolearn.com/2014/01/10/group-ism-the-larger-problem-behind-racism-nationalism-and-many-other-isms/)*, which has been coined by a number of online writers to classify all prejudicial *-ism*s.  However, be careful not to confuse *group-ism* with *[groupism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/groupism)*, which means a person's tendency to conform to the expectations and standards of the group(s) to which that person belongs.  Perhaps someday, *groupism* will absorb *group-ism*.

Answer (score 1):

The terms used most commonly to describe a feeling of blanket antagonism toward a group of people based on that group's defining characteristic differ from one such characteristic to another.

I ran a series of Google Books searches for the years 1900–2000 comparing the frequency of occurrence of the terms *bias*, *bigotry*, *discrimination*, *hostility*, *intolerance*, and *prejudice* in association with five adjectives: *racial*, *religious*, *ethnic*, *sexual*, and *gender*. Here are the resulting Ngram charts.

First, for terms attached to *racial*:

[image]

This chart suggests that the most common relevant phrases in the context of racial antagonism are *racial discrimination* (yellow line), *racial prejudice* (red line), and *racial bias* (green line).

Second, for terms attached to *religious*:

[image]

Here the top three choices are *religious intolerance* (navy blue line), *religious discrimination* (yellow line) and *religious bigotry* (blue line), with *religious prejudice* (red line) somewhat less frequent since 1960 than it was during the 40 years before that.

Third, for terms attached to *ethnic*:

[image]

Here *ethnic discrimination* (yellow line) and *ethnic prejudice* (red line) easily outdistance the other four options.

Fourth, for terms attached to *sexual*:

[image]

Here *sexual discrimination* (yellow line) is vastly more common than any other choice, with *sexual bias* (green line) slightly ahead of the rest of the trailing pack.

Fifth, for terms attached to *gender*:

[image]

Here *gender discrimination* (yellow line) and *gender bias* (green line) dwarf the other four options.

These charts indicate that *discrimination* is the most common term associated with four of the five adjectives (all but *religious*, though it may not be more common than *bias* in the context of *gender*) and that it is a strong contender there as well.

*Prejudice* has its strongest showings in connection with *racial* and *ethnic*. *Bias* is most prominent in connection with *gender*. *Intolerance* is the most frequent of the five nouns I examined in the context of *religious*. *Bigotry* appears in the top three options only once—in association with *religious*. *Hostility* does best in connection with *ethnic*, but it is the least frequent option in most other situations.

For application across all categories, *discrimination* may be the most suitable choice; it has certainly experienced a remarkable increase in frequency of use over the past half century in most contexts. Nevertheless, for specific types of group-based animosity, other terms may have special resonance.

Comment: discrimination and antagonism are two different things. The former requires an act. I can be disgusted by orcs and have a bias against them, but if I never meet one there is no consequence.

Comment: @Oldcat: I think that a lot depends on how you interpret the word _discrimination_. I agree with you to this extent: In the context of law, _discrimination_ refers to speech, conduct, or action that is harmful to the target group, whereas _antagonism_ can be silent and (theoretically at least) without real-world consequences. But Merriam-Webster's relevant definition of _discrimination_ (3b) includes "outlook" among its terms: "prejudiced or prejudicial outlook, action, or treatment." Under this definition, I think, a prejudiced outlook toward orcs would qualify as "orc discrimination."

Answer (score 0):

discrimination
or, perhaps
intolerance

Answer (score 0):

I like the word **aversion**.

i.e.:  "He clearly has an *aversion* to immigrants."

Answer (score 0):

I think "racist" is the common vernacular.  You cite "against" as in derogatory so that seems to be how the label is applied, whether or not to an actual race but group.

You can make a positive like so-and-so are a rich and industrious people and that's socially acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

For an adjective rather than a noun you could use 'predisposed'. It's more usual for it to be followed by 'towards' to mean 'in favour of', but 'predisposed against' sounds fine to me.